# Vue3 Apexcharts: X-axis not showing dates properly

Tags: vue.js, datetime, vuejs3, axis, apexcharts

I have an issue with the datetime x-axis of an Apexchart:
[image]

It should display 26.09, 27.09 and 28.09 only and each tick should be aligned with the bar.

This is the data I am using:

```
[{
    "x": 1632614400000,
    "y": 1548.0806194763181
},
{
    "x": 1632700800000,
    "y": 2983.7424364471435
},
{
    "x": 1632787200000,
    "y": 606.8401075286865
}]
```

I have already tried to change the "tickAmount"  of the x-axis but without an acceptable result.
Example: tickAmount=3
[image]

```
     xaxis: {
      type: "datetime",
      labels: {
        formatter: function(val, timestamp) {
          return moment(timestamp).format("DD.MM");
        },
      },
      tickAmount: 3
    },
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Let me know if you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this data format:

```js
[{
  name: 'Example name', 
  data: 
      [[1632614400000,1548.0806194763181],
      [1632614400000,1548.0806194763181]]
  }]
```

Comment: unfortunately still the same behaviour